# Changing date to German standard in CV of Share-Latex

Tags: moderncv, german, cv, english

At the moment the date of my CV in Share-Latex is written in English i.e. `October 12, 2017`. But I would change it into German firstly (`Oktober` instead of `October`) and secondly to the more common format `DD MM YYYY`. But in this CV the Date seems to be predefined because I can't find the code for the date. Can you help me?

```
   %% start of file `template.tex'.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green}                              % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'


% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using


% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.77]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{bla}{bla}                            
\address{bla bla}{bla bla}
\phone[mobile]{bla bla}                   % 
\email{bla bla}                          

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %            content
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{bla bla}{ \\ bla bla
\\bla bla}

\opening{\textbf{bla bla} \newline 
\newline 
Sehr geehrter Damen und Herren,}



\makelettertitle

bla bla

\vspace{0.2cm}

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}


\makeletterclosing



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try adding `\usepackage[de-DE-1996]{datetime2}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` to your preamble ...

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green} 


% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % <========================================


% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.77]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{bla}{bla}                            
\address{bla bla}{bla bla}
\phone[mobile]{bla bla}                   % 
\email{bla bla}                          

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %            content
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{bla bla}{bla\\ bla bla
\\bla bla}

\opening{\textbf{bla bla} \newline 
\newline 
Sehr geehrter Damen und Herren,}



\makelettertitle

bla bla

\vspace{0.2cm}

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}


\makeletterclosing



\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for!